# Debian Depends - Possible to be Dependent on A | (B and C)?

Tags: debian

Is it possible to make a debian package dependent on either package A or both B AND C AND D?

Basically I have three packages that replace a single one in a newer version. I want to be able to have the package I'm creating dependent on either the old package or the three newer ones. I am able to get around this with a meta-package that is dependent on those three, however I would like to avoid adding MORE meta-packages into my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it as `A | B, A | C`.

The problem: it is not obvious for user, on the other hand, you say that for functionality X you need either A or B, and for functionality Y, you need either A or C. But if A is obsolete, the inverse dependence is better (`B | A, C | A`), so that B and C are taken as default, if A is not installed.

But if B and C together replaces A, probably it is better to have maybe C as true replacement, and B as *depends* (or *recommend*) of C, and having C also as *replace* A.